# How to write custom-file-input text with css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap4 to design my html page and I'm implementing a `custom-file-input` bar.

I want to get the three labels of the input bar ("Choose file", "Browse", "Upload") from my `css` file, so I've defined three custom classes and their content in the `css` file. Here is the code:

```
.CHOOSE_FILE_LABEL::before{content: 'Choose file';}
.BROWSE_BTN_LABEL::after{content: 'Browse';}
.UPLOAD_BTN_LABEL::after{content: 'Upload';}
```

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFileInput">
    <label class="custom-file-label CHOOSE_FILE_LABEL BROWSE_BTN_LABEL" for="customFileInput"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-success UPLOAD_BTN_LABEL" type="button" id="uploadBtn"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then I want to replace the label of the input bar ("Choose file") with the name of the file when a file is selected. So I use the following JS code:

```
// replace "Choose file" with the file name
document.getElementById("customFileInput").addEventListener('change', function (e)  
{
  e.preventDefault();
  var file_input =  document.getElementById("customFileInput");
  var file_name = file_input.files[0].name;
  var next_sibling = e.target.nextElementSibling;
  next_sibling.innerText = file_name;
});
```

The problem is that the name of the selected file is concatenated with (and not replaced by) "Choose file". Can I do that with JS or should I change my `css` file?

Here is the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/5csLd90b/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change your file input to be `required` then you can use CSS `:valid` and next selector to target the label, eg:

```
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFileInput" required>
```

```
.custom-file-input:valid + .CHOOSE_FILE_LABEL::before{content: '';}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/50wqt4gx/

Otherwise you can add a class using js to your file input (or label) and apply `::before` based on that class, eg:

```
file_input.classList.add("hasfile")
```

```
.custom-file-input.hasfile + .CHOOSE_FILE_LABEL::before{content: '';}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and working solution is that you do this in js func:

```
document.getElementById("customFileInput").addEventListener('change', function (e)  
{
  e.preventDefault();
  var file_input =  document.getElementById("customFileInput");
  var file_name = file_input.files[0].name;
  var next_sibling = e.target.nextElementSibling;
  
    var file_input_label =  document.getElementById("file_input_label");
  file_input_label.classList.remove('CHOOSE_FILE_LABEL')
  next_sibling.innerText = file_name;
});
```

and add id to the label like this:

```
<label id="file_input_label" class="custom-file-label CHOOSE_FILE_LABEL BROWSE_BTN_LABEL" for="customFileInput"></label>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Even your solution works!